# From data-url attribute value using javascript navigate to the url

Tags: javascript

It is an unordered list with id of "menu" that is used to dynamically create menus on a page. This list is populated by list-items that contain links to other pages as shown below. using JavaScript, attach events to these list-items so clicking them will navigate the user to its corresponding page.

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li data-url="home.html">Home</li>
    <li data-url="about.html">About</li>
    <li data-url="contact.html">Contact</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: OK. Do you have problem with this statement? Looks relatively normal - if you need spelling check or grammar suggestions - this is wrong place. Show your current code that you have problem with to be valid question here.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a homework assignment or something of that sort. You'll get a lot more out of it if you try to do the work yourself, first! Regardless, here's a solution (if you have jQuery and assuming that the `data-url`s are supposed to be relative to the domain).

```
$( '#menu li' ).click( function () {
    window.location.href = '/' + $( this ).data( 'url' );
} );
```

You'll probably want to read about [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) in jQuery. If you don't have jQuery, [Using data-* attributes in JavaScript and CSS](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/10/using-data-attributes-in-javascript-and-css/) is a useful resource (and even if you do use jQuery, still worth a look).

If you don't understand how the event handler (`.click(...`) works, you can see [jQuery docs on .click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/). For some information about event handling in general, [Wikipedia "Event handler"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_%28computing%29#Event_handler) is always good.

Good luck with your future programming projects! :)

*(And, seriously, try it yourself first. It's so much more fun.)*

P.S. [Here is a demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/dpLZZ/) using your example data.